# Конструктор класса

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток.

Скажите, как можно организовать конструктор, который бы инициализировал поля указателя класса и можно ли вообще такое вытворять? ) Вопрос для собственного развития. )

```
class List{
    private:
        int *pnumber;
        char *pIDE;
        char * padress;
    public:
        List(){}//какое-то тело
};
```

Хочу в `main()-е` при создании объекта внести данные. Например:

```
int main(){
    List P(1111,"asdf","fgh");
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А кто мешает? Никто. Нужно только объявить конструктор с тремя параметрами и все правильно скопировать. Также раз в конструкторе решили работать с ручным выделением памяти, неплохо и освобождать память в деструкторе (чтобы не было утечек).

Я также добавил метод print, который выводит значения (для контроля).

Но этот подход плохой. Он не плюсовый, это подход чистого си. Если просто не побаловаться и разобраться - то нормально. Если же для нормального кода - используйте тип `std::string` - он сложность работы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class List{
    private:
        int *pnumber;
        char *pIDE;
        char * padress;
    public:
        List(){}//какое-то тело
        List(int number, const char* IDE, const char * address) {
            pnumber = new int;
            *pnumber = number;

            pIDE = new char[strlen(IDE)+1];
            strcpy(pIDE, IDE);

            padress = new char[strlen(address)+1];
            strcpy(padress, address);
        }

        ~List() {
            delete pnumber;
            delete[] pIDE;
            delete[] padress;
        }
        void print() {
            cout << *pnumber << endl;
            cout << pIDE << endl;
            cout << padress << endl;
        }
    };

 int main(){
     List P(1111,"asdf","fgh");
     P.print();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, с конструктором не знал, как поступить, а теперь стало ясно.